# IBM Datapower - How to create a MPG that handles OAuth2.0 to connect to a provider API

Tags: ibm-datapower

First I need to apologize because maybe this should be obvious but I`m not familiar with all the configurations on the datapower.

I need to consume resources from an external provider. They gave me the client id and client secret which I can use to request an access token from them. In other words, they are the resource owners and they have the authorization services.

### My question is, Is the datapower able to handle this client id and secret id to request for access tokens to the external providers auth endpoint?

The available documentation I have read about talk about how to setup Oauth security on a MPG but only when the resourcees and authetication services are located behind the datapower, not outside as in my case.

I know it is able to handle security certificates from other servers internally on my organization and whenever they expire we need to update those certificates, what about Oauth 2.0? is it able to handle client ids and client secret ids to request access tokens?

The grant_type we require is client_credentials, here some documentation I found but it seems it only applies when the auth services and resource owners are located behind the datapower on our network.

Here some documentation I found,
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/grant-type-scenario-client-credentials

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/api-connect/10.0.1.x?topic=overview-configuring-third-party-oauth-provider

https://medium.com/@lakshmi.soumya18/oauth-journey-in-datapower-appliance-using-client-credential-grant-type-d35a43136e6c